# JXMapViewer Mashup example

Tags: java, swing, openstreetmap, netbeans-7, jxmapviewer

Im working on an application and was trying things from

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/13/mapping-mashups-with-jxmapviewer.html

but while trying as in Fig 8 i got stuck as WikiWaypoint class is not in my jar files...
Please help.

Please ask if you want any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article to which you refer contains your answer:

> For each entry the code creates a WikiWaypoint, which is just a subclass of Waypoint with an extra field to store the title of the entry

So it is basically a class he created, extending from the `Waypoint` class and which adds an extra field. So you will have to create that class yourself, and not trying to find it in any of the jars

Comment: Yes... you were right.. i tried and finally got it.. THANKS a lot..
:)